# Android M - GoogleAccountCredential setSelectedAccount doesn't work - name must not be null

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

On the Android M-Preview `GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccount` doesn't seem to work.

When debugging, I noticed that after calling that method, the `selectedAccount` and `accountName` fields of the object are still null.

While debugging you can see that my variable `accountName` is not empty or null, I call the `.setSelectedAccountName()`, but as you can see in the debug window, the field in the GoogleAccountCredential is still null.

[image: Debugging window code]
[image: Debugging window debug values]

I think this can be related to some permissions? On my Manifest, I have the following permissions declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I know that the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission you get for free on M (According to https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#normal ), but the other two permissions are "unknown" to the M-Preview. So maybe, it's that?

Comment: I swear, M is so buggy right meow, it makes me pull my hair out. Good luck to you man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` has protectionLevel:dangerous and is now part of the Contacts permission group, which means you should request it at runtime using the new `Activity.requestPermissions()`

Only then can you interact with accounts created by other apps on your device.

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation, the android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS is listed in the normal permissions. https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#normal

Anyway, I just tried to request that permission, and it works now. I was assuming that that permission was in the NORMAL list.

Comment: That particular change was made between Preview 2 and Preview 3, someone must have missed this one spot in the documentation. I'll see if I can get it fixed.

Meanwhile you can get a list of all permission groups and protection levels using:
adb shell pm list permissions -g -f

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any info on why this permission is considered dangerous? Also, it is really bad that when we ask for this permission, there is a dialog saying "Allow APP XYZ to access your contacts". I'm not trying to access their contacts, just their account names... I think lots of users will be scared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Use setSelectedAccount() instead of setSelectedAccountName()

```
 mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        // to set accountName manually instead of prompting user to select it
        mCredential.setSelectedAccount(new Account("xyz@gmail.com", "com.android.example"));
```

set the account that you want to set as the email and you can give your package name as the second parameter.