# Android calendar API account selection

Tags: android, calendar, google-play-services

I followed the Android calendar api integration from the [official site](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) and I encountered some issues.

The 'choose an account' dialog doesn't stop to pop up. I select an account from the list and instead of continuing, the dialog pops up again.

I tried debugging and found that after this line the `mCredential` object is still null

```
mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
```

even though the account name contains the real name. I believe that this is the problem, but I didn't find out how to resolve it.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Have you checked on the earlier instance of `mCredential` if it has a value?

Comment: Yes, it always null, even after I set real account name manually. I`m testing on my device (one plus one) with custom rom of android 6. I just check on another device witch runs lolipop and its work`s. So the problem is with android 6.0 or with my custom rom I guess.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.

I raed this question:
[Android M - GoogleAccountCredential setSelectedAccount doesn't work - name must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270036/android-m-googleaccountcredential-setselectedaccount-doesnt-work-name-must)

The problem was that I didn`t request on runtime the "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission.
All tough it was not written at the log cat as an error, after adding it solve my problem.